# an invariant of $C^{*}$ algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

consider the following property (invariant) for complex  $C^{*}$ algebras:

"$T(x)=x^{*}$ is the only non zero $\mathbb{R}$-linear map on $A$ which satisfies $T(x)T(y)=T(yx)$."

**Questions:**

1)Some examples?

2)Does this property implies that $A$ has trivial center?

Comment: Is $A$ an *operator*, or an *algebra*?  The symbol "$A$" is used both ways in your post!

Comment: @RobertLewis  $A$ is a $C^{*}$ algebra.

Comment: @RobertLewis thank you  very much. I corrected it.

Comment: My pleasure, sir!  Good question, +1!

Comment: @RobertLewis thank you for your positive opinion on this question

Comment: I was about to write up an answer in the negative based on the counterexample $T_1(x) = x^\dagger$ and $T_2x = x^T$ where $x \in M(n, \Bbb C)$ acting on $\Bbb C^n$ with the usual inner product $\sum \bar z_i z_i$, but now that you've added the idempotent condition in no longer works! ;-)

Comment: @RobertLewis  Now I realize that my question is obviously trivial because any automorphism of a commutative C*  algebra is a counterexample. So I will revise the question in a new version.

Comment: Do automorphisms satisfy $T(xy) = T(y)T(x)$ or $T(xy) = T(x)T(y)$?

Comment: @RobertLewis In commutative case they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose (as in the current version of the question) that conjugation is the only $\mathbb R$-linear map satisfying $T(xy)=T(y)T(x)$. We will see that the $C^*$-algebra $A$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.

Let the $C^*$-algebra $A$ be faithfully represented on a Hilbert space $H$. Let $U$ be any unitary on $H$. Then $$T_U(x) = U^*x^*U$$ will be an anti-automorphism of $A$. So if conjugation is the only anti-automorphism of $A$, then we require that $A$ commutes with $U$ for every unitary $U$ on the Hilbert space $H$. As every operator in $B(H)$ is a linear combination of unitaries, it follows that $A'= B(H)$. Thus $A \subseteq A'' \subseteq B(H)'= \mathbb C \cdot id_H$. Here $A'$ denotes the commutant of $A$, the set of all bounded linear operators that commute with $A$.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. it works for unital case without needing to faithfull representation. But I am not sure that your argument works for non unital case.  Why $T_{U}$ is an operator on $A$?

Comment: I think your argument works if you consider a unitization of $A$ which contains $A$ as an ideal. thanks again for your answer

Comment: @Tom: your argument works even if only maps into $A$ are considered; please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question does not consider $A$ represented, it seems reasonable to assume that $T:A\to A$. In that case, Tom's argument does not work as stated. But it can be saved: using his same idea, we would deduce that $A$ commutes with $U$ for each unitary in $A$; as $A$ is spanned by its unitaries, it follows that $A$ is abelian.

So all representations of $A$ are one-dimensional, and they all satisfy $\pi(xy)=\pi(y)\pi(x)$. By the uniqueness, there is a single one-dimensional representation, i.e. $A=\mathbb C$.